# Scroll on fixed DIV with main page scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm recreating a Wordpress theme myself and I'm facing a problem with the sidebar.

It's fixed and fits my 1280x720 monitor but if you see the website in a screen, for example of 800x400 the sidebar doesn't fit.

As it's fixed, the content hides when the screen is small.

I can use `overflow: scroll` but what I want is the div to scroll down when you use the main scrollbar as seen in the actual theme:

https://twentyfifteendemo.wordpress.com/

PS: I'm using the theme for **personal uses** not commercial!

EDIT: Here's my page: http://pvlts.ga/

Comment: Added my website so you can see it :)

Comment: What do you want to achieve when the screen is small? Do you want to re-flow the content in some other way (such as put the sidebar on top)? If so you should definitely look at either the *flex* CSS property: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ or use a grid system such as http://960.gs/ (there are dozens of grids out there)

Comment: I want that, if the screen height is smaller than `.info` you can scroll it becomes static until your scroll reaches the end of the div

Answer (score 0):

By changing the "fixed" position of the class **info** to "absolute", it scrolls normally (line 16 of your stylesheet).

```
.info { position: absolute; }
```

EDIT: If you want to keep your sidebar fixed on bigger screens, you can just use media queries to target only screens that are smaller than 1100px wide, like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) { .info {position: absolute; } }
```